# Use withStyles in the functional components to update font size of menu item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I would like to change font size of menu item(`material ui v3`) in my react app. I am trying to do that using `withStyles` but I am facing errors. I have a functional component and here is my code.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  menu: {
    fontSize: '4rem',
  },
});

interface Props {
  lang: string;
  rate: string;
}

export const withStyles( styles )(App): React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  let search = props.id ? false : true;
  return <MenuItem className={classes.menu}>Foo</MenuItem>;
};
```

Can someone help to use `withStyles` correctly in the functional component?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for Material UI V3:

```
import { withStyles, createStyles, Theme, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    menu: {
      fontSize: "4rem"
    }
  });

interface IProps {
  classes: {
    menu: string,
  },
  someProp?: string,
  lang?: string;
  rate?: string;
}

export const App = withStyles(styles)((props: IProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem className={props.classes.menu}>Foo</MenuItem>
      <p>{props.someProp}</p>
    </>
  );
});
```

To give props is pretty usual stuff, in case of my example it is:

```
<App someProp="data from prop" />
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-noyce-lyy5y?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: How would I pass props here?

Comment: Props are “destructured”, you can change { classes } to props and refer further as props.classes or any other that you pass on

Comment: Its giving me props values as undefined when I use it in place of classes

Comment: I have edited the code above. You can see I am trying to use props.id but I am getting props as undefined.

Comment: I've edited my code to simplify props a bit for you, also added interface and edited sandbox so you can inspect working example. If `id` is undefined there must be some problem in delivery of that data, are you sure it's coming along fine? (I don't know what else is going on in your code, I assume this is just a tiny bit of it)